# has_one relationship with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, has-one

lets say I have 2 models like News, Clients.
Using paperclip's default options, I need to create for each of them additional columns like (photo_file_name .....)
but I just want to create different model, let's say Asset

**asset.rb**

```
  belongs_to :client
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:small => "300x300>"}
```

**client.rb**

```
  has_one :asset, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset
```

**clients_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @client = Client.new
    @client.build_asset
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for @client, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :asset do |asset| %>
      <%= asset.label :photo %><br/>
      <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

For now this is working, but how to show it in show view ? i'm doing this:

```
  <%= image_tag @client.url(:small) %>
```

I know this is not correct, because @client.asset does not have url column,
how to do it ?

Comment: `@client.asset.photo.url(:small)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Mikhail Nikalyukin said, you should call

```
<%= image_tag @client.photo.url(:small) %>
```

instead of

```
<%= image_tag @client.url(:small) %>
```